# Javascript timed popup alert with location.href

Tags: javascript

I'm making a message that pops up after 10 seconds and after "ok" is clicked the user is redirected to a different page.  I have this so far.

```
if (setTimeout(function() { !alert("my message"); }, 10000)); {
location.href = "/some/url"
}
```

It just redirects right when the page loads, no message and no "ok" click.  Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: because the page exits and the other code will not run all that is in the if is the id of the timeout which is truthy. There is no waiting.

Comment: `setTimeout` returns a number, and is asynchronous.

Comment: use the [window.confirm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be something like this.

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    if (window.confirm("Go?")) { 
      location.href = "/some/url";
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: This got me to what works!! Thank you.  

setTimeout(function() {
      if (!window.alert("Go?")) {
    location.href = "/some/url";
   }
  }, 10000);

Comment: @JayyCodez `if (!window.alert("Go?")) ` make zero sense

Answer (score 0):

the setTimeout returns the id of the timeout. So you are just checking if the id is truthy. That code does not have a wait until the user clicks the button.

If you want to wait until after the user hits the okay on the alert, than you need to put the location.href line after the alert.

```
window.setTimeout( function () {
   alert("x");
   window.location.href = "/a/b/c";
}, 10000);
```